# Pegar texto de uma determinada coluna com jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

Boa tarde.

Preciso pegar o valor de um `DropDownList` em uma determinada coluna de uma tabela.

Esta seria a tabela:

```
 @model IEnumerable<Santander.Web.MVC.ValidacaoGanhadores.Models.Ganhadores>


<table id="tbValidacao">
    <thead>
        <tr style="height: 35px">
            <td></td>
            <td>Manter</td>
            <td>Matricula</td>
            <td>Nome</td>
            <td>Status</td>
            <td>Validado</td>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @{
            var count = 1;

            foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                @*item.Matricula.Contains("999") ? "Nao" : "Sim"*@
                <tr style="height: 35px">
                    <td>@count</td>
                    <td>@Html.DropDownList("DropManter", listItems)</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBox("txtMatricula", "", new { @readonly = "readonly" })</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBox("txtNome", "", new { @readonly = "readonly" })</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBox("txtStatus", "", new { @readonly = "readonly" })</td>
                    <td>@(item.Rede == "Rede SP Capital" ? 1 : 2)</td>
                </tr>
                count = count + 1;
            }

        }






    </tbody>
</table>
```

O número de linhas é variável, preciso pegar o valor deste `DropDownList` de cada linha, assim que ele for mudado.

Eu estava tentando do seguinte modo:

```
 $('#tbValidacao tbody tr td').change(function () {

        var conteudo = $('#DropManter option:selected').text();
        alert(conteudo);

    })
```

Só que sempre me retorna o valor da primeira linha.

Comment: Você que o valor referente ao DropDown ou o texto q ele exibe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paulo, para garantir que o seu HTML será valido, te aconselho a atribuir um ID único para cada elemento da sua pagina, então te aconselho a usar este `cont` ao seu favor, porem você pode manter todos os DropDownList com o mesmo `name`

```
@Html.DropDownList("DropManter-" + cont, listItems, new { @Name = "DropManter" })
```

então atribua o evento change direto ao DropDownList (a.k.a `select`) com o `name='DropManter'`, você pode acessar o `select` atual pelo `event.target` e/ou `this`:

```
$("select[name='DropManter']").change(function (event) {
    var dropManter = $(event.target);
    var conteudo = $('option:selected', dropManter).text();
    alert(conteudo);
})
```

Comment: Desta maneira funcionou, só poderia me esclarecer onde que o código esta diferenciando pelo ID?

Comment: Paulo, no exemplo acima não estou utilizando o `id` para fazer a seleção do elemento DOM, mas sim o `name`, mencionei o `id`, pq dois elementos com o mesmo `id` não é sintaticamente valido para o HTML.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado pela resposta, esta fazendo o que eu queria

Answer (score 1):

A opção que o @TobyMosque postou funciona, e será sua melhor opção, caso deseje enviar esses valores para algum lugar. Irei deixar apenas uma forma alternativa usando o `$(this)` que o @TobyMosque comentou.

Para isso, basta alterar o `script` para isso:

```
            <script>
                $("select[name='DropManter']").change(function(){
                    var valor = $(this).val();
                    var texto = $('option:selected', $(this)).text();
                    alert(valor + ': ' + texto );
                });
            </script>
```

Nesse exemplo ele está será executado ao manipular qualquer elemento (select) dentro do id `tbValidacao`. Ao alterar o valor ele irá selecionar o valor do `select` que está sendo manipulado no momento.

Olhe um exemplo no [dotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wQ2n4t).

Answer (score 0):

Olá, para pegar o valor "value" de um select costumo usar em jQuery o .val()
exemplo:

```
$("#usuario").change(function () {
   alert($("#usuario").val());
});
```